# What did Shin Nihon Kikaku (SNK) originally manufacture in 1973?

Tags: history, early-computer

The company SNK was originally Shin Nihon Kikaku, founded in 1973.  What did Shin Nihon Kikaku originally manufacture in 1973?  I would assume some sort of primitive computers or calculators, but searched Google and can only find answers pertaining to SNK in 1978.

Comment: Have you tried to look up at least according Wiki Pages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*(For most parts taken from the Japanese Wiki)*

Eikichi Kawasaki operated a coffee shop and civil engineering business. When in 1973 asked to finance an **electric engineering company** of a friend, he acquired that company himself and founded *Shin Nihon Kikaku* (literally *Project New Japan*).

---

Further Steps:

- 1978 the company structure was changed, legally founding the [later SNK](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNK_(1978%E5%B9%B4%E8%A8%AD%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%AE%E4%BC%81%E6%A5%AD))
- The same year they ventured first into video games with a Breakout clone called Battleship Yamato (センカンヤマト), cashing in on the popularity of [Space Battleship Yamato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Battleship_Yamato) Anime and a licenced Space Invaders copy.
- On products and advertisement the Kanji abbreviation *エス・エヌ・ケイ* (literally SNK) was used
- Starting 1981 all material used the Latin abbreviation SNK as company name
- In 1986 the [company was restructured](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNK_(1978%E5%B9%B4%E8%A8%AD%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%AE%E4%BC%81%E6%A5%AD)#%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A8%E3%83%8C%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B1%E3%82%A4_%E6%99%82%E4%BB%A3), now the official name was *株式会社エス・エヌ・ケイ*, roughly SNK & Co [LLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_liability_company)
- 2001 the company went bankrupt and it's own subsidiary **[Playmore LLC](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNK_(2001%E5%B9%B4%E8%A8%AD%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%AE%E4%BC%81%E6%A5%AD))** (Latin spelling - by now Japanese law allowed company names in Latin) bought all game assets. Kawasaki still held >85% of the capital for this company
- 2003 Playmore changed its name to SNK Playmore LLC
- 2015 Kawasakis share of SNK Playmore was acquired by a Chinese investemnt company
- 2016 The name was changed again to SNK and focussed again to capitalize on their rich history
- Over 2020 to 2022 the Saudi investment fund [MiSK Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiSK_Foundation) bought the majority of SNK thru their subsidiary [Electronic Game Development Company](https://dotesports.com/news/reignite-turn-up-the-heat-late-on-in-steelseries-prime-invitational-to-claim-5k-top-prize)

Comment: Great info, but if I'm, not mistaken, the very question at hand is literally what did they manufacture before 78?  (ie 73 - 78)

Comment: @Fattie Which is what the part **above** the additional information is. Hence the divider. Chck the highlighted part.

Comment: I've downvoted this because it doesn't answer the question

Comment: @knol  The answer is clearly highlighted and separated from additional information. So how is it not answer to the question asked?

Comment: @fectin I'm open to any better naming for a company that designs and builds electrically driven machines to customer spec - keep in mind, that's the time before Electronics, control was done by switches, relays and sets of huge resistors.

Comment: @Raffzahn that’s still electronics. They built analog electronics. (Or relay-logic controllers, if that’s all they did)

Comment: @fectin Sorry, but no. Electronics require use of active components (tubes, semiconductors) for control. With only passive components (resistors, switches, capacitors and coils) it's still called electric engineering. It wasn't until the late 70s that electronics started to creep into that area. Complex operation were not controlled by processors but relay logic or, for higher power by motor operated cam switches (both digital) :)

Comment: I'm being picky :) I'm not satisfied until someone can find a picture of a washing machine with an SNK-branded controller board. Right now, the question asks 'what did they manufacture?' and your answer says 'Kawasaki acquired an engineering company'.

Comment: @knol Well, check again, it says _electric_ engineering company, they did electric engineering stuff. And as I understand the hints, it's not controller boards for washing machines either. Not at least due the fact that washing machines in the 70s (and in fact way into the 90s) didn't have controller boards at all, but rather one complex electro-mechanical cam switch executing the programmed sequence. Not something a small company does.